# Replace Angular's updateValueAndValidity with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am testing (automated testing, using the webdriverio framework) an Angular web app which checks the input in a time input (consisting of two HTML input fields) and adds a little notice if the input is not correct.

[image]

Unfortunately, if I change the value of e.g. the minute input field using

```
document.querySelector("#minutesInput").value=""
```

the "Incorrect format" notice does not appear, because some event is not triggered as opposed to deletion of the input in the minute field by keyboard.

Are there any events I could dispatch using Javascript so Angular's `updateValueAndValidity` is either triggered or somehow imitated? I.e. I need something that can be run from the browser's (Chrome) console that will make the "Incorrect format" hint appear.

Comment: `document.querySelector` is not part of Angular's world. Use Angular entirely, or don't use it at all, but if you use Angular and try to mix it with regular JS events, it's not gonna work. Use `[value]`, `[(value)]`, all kinds of Angular things, but forget about `getElementById` and such.

Comment: @JeremyThille I clarified what I'm doing and what I want to achieve. I don't really know anything about Angular itself.

Comment: Have you tried to use the framwork `clearValue` method? Usually it should trigger the correct events. Ref: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/clearValue.html

Comment: I'm still using wbedriverio v4, which has the `clearElement` method, which also doesn't trigger the notice to appear.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("#minutesInput").value=""
```

There is no such *user* who can magically set the value to an empty string *without* using an input device like a *mouse* or *keyboard*.

Everything that *happens* during your tests when using the webdriver should be performed via an input device.

```js
WebElement textInputElement = driver.findElement(By.id("minutesInput"));
textInputElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

It does not matter how the HTML page is managed. You could be testing Angular, React, Vue or have no JavaScript at all. The test should be purely from the perspective of the user.

Comment: In theory, yes, in practice Selenium throws a `RuntimeException` due to an `UnknownCommand` when I use `browser.keys()`.